# Constructing string from parameter?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I was wondering if yall knew how to construct the parameter "input" i have below so that it can be thrown into a parser and used to create a tree. This is an infix postfix program that is based on classes and uses variable expressions. If you need more info let me know

```
arithmetic_expression::arithmetic_expression(RPNstring input)  //constructor
{


}

arithmetic_expression::arithmetic_expression(const arithmetic_expression &inExpression)
{





}
```

Rpnstring coming from

```
#ifndef AE_H
#define AE_H

class RPNstring
{
public:
RPNstring(std::string inString){ expression = inString; };
std::string getString(){return(expression);}

private:
std::string expression;
};

class Infixstring
{
public:
Infixstring(std::string inString){ expression = inString; };
std::string getString(){return(expression);};
private:
std::string expression;
};

class arithmetic_expression
{
public:
arithmetic_expression(RPNstring inString);
arithmetic_expression(Infixstring inString);
arithmetic_expression(const arithmetic_expression &inExpression);  //Copy constructor
~arithmetic_expression();  //Destructor
arithmetic_expression & operator=(const arithmetic_expression &inExpression); //assignment          operator
void printRPN();
void printInfix();
int evaluate_Expression(std::map< std::string, int > ipmap);
```

and

```
RPNstring in1("3  2 + xyz *");
arithmetic_expression expression1(in1);
std::cout<<"Expression 1"<< std::endl;
expression1.printInfix();
expression1.printRPN();
std::cout<<"----
```

and inString from

```
class Tree
{
public:
Tree(std::string input,Tree *leftSubTree=NULL,Tree *rightSubTree=NULL);
Tree(const Tree &inTree);   //COPY CONSTRUCTOR
~Tree(); //DESTRUCTOR
```

and also...

```
Tree::Tree(std::string input,Tree *leftSubTree,Tree *rightSubTree){
Op = input;
leftPtr = leftSubTree;
rightPtr = rightSubTree;
int num;
if (input == "+"|input == "-"|input == "*"|input == "/")
            NodeType = TYPE_OPERATOR;
else if(std::istringstream(Op)>>num)
    NodeType = TYPE_NUMBER;
else
    NodeType = TYPE_VARIABLE;
```

Comment: arithmetic_expression(RPNstring inString);
arithmetic_expression(Infixstring inString);
the typedef of RPNstring and Infixstring would be nice to know

Comment: arithmetic_expression myExpression(RPNstring("mystring"));

Comment: Given what `RPNstring` and `Infixstring` are actually doing, why not just declare them as typedefs instead?  `typedef std::string RPNstring;` and `typedef std::string  Infixstring;`, respectively. Then you don't have to cast a `char*` to a `RPNstring` explicitally: `arithmetic_expression myExpression("mystring");`

Comment: @RemyLebeau why try to understand the logic of the ill informed, as they say, this is c++, and it's your foot

Comment: ty! I suppose your recommendation would provide simplicity, ill give it a go

Comment: well while the questions is still fresh, any guidance on the copy constructor? i did  tree = Tree(*(inexpression.tree)) but no good